# How to deploy non-web Java application to EC2 via AWS BeanStalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does AWS Elastic BeanStalk support deploy non-web Java application to EC2?

That is to say, I want to pass a jar to EC2 instance, and make it auto run when EC2 instance started.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, you have to run Java based web applications or worker tier applications, both have to be modeled as web apps.

You could run a tomcat app that does some backend processing work but does not perform the usual functions of a web app.